# SQL syntax error in Mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to run the query

```
select * from Order;
```

I m getting the following syntax error in sql fiddle. 
Could not figure out the correct syntax.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Order' at line 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aee9e/62

Comment: Order is a reserved word.  wrap in backtick

Comment: Googling this would have avoided this question entirely and it's been asked more times than you may think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Order` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html).  Change your query to use backticks:

```
select * from `Order`;
```

Answer (score -1):

Order is a reserved keyword for mysql refer to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html);

Simply change your table name from Order to orders.
Bye!

Comment: True that `order` is a reserved word. But telling them that *"Simply change your table name from Order to orders."* is your suggestion, but they may have to keep that name for unknown reasons. `Order` is a valid name for a table, although not recommended. It can still be used if ticks `\`` are placed around its name. That's not my downvote, but you may have gotten it because of what you said; I can't speak for them but it may be the reason why.